# Compare values from mysql database in two texbox without submitting the form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I want to check the values from either one of the two textboxes text boxes that matches the value with the other without submitting the form. The keypress event is handling this, sending the value from jour_info.php page to get_sid.php page. I have two files

1. jour_info.php
2. get_sid.php

The code in the first file

```
 <form method="post" name="journ_form" >
P-ISSN/ISBN<br/><input name="printissn" id="printissn_input" type="text" value="">
                <input type="text" name="pissnsid"  id="pissnsid" style="width: 30px;" autocomplete="off" value="">

                <span style="color: red;" id="feedback"></span>
 </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#feedback').load('get_sid.php').show();

    $('#printissn_input').keyup(function(){

    $.post('get_sid.php', {printissn: journ_form.printissn.value},
      function(result) {
      document.getElementById('pissnsid').value = result;
   }); 
  });


   $('#pissnsid').keyup(function(){
    $.post('get_sid.php', {pissnsid: journ_form.pissnsid.value},
      function(result) {
        document.getElementById('printissn_input').value = result;
     });
   });
  });
```

The code in the second file

```
    <?php
    include 'auth.php';

     $printissn = $_POST['printissn'];
     $pissnsid = $_POST['pissnsid'];

     if($printissn){
      $check = mysql_query("SELECT printissn, pissnsid FROM jour_entries WHERE    printissn='$printissn'");
      $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
        $get_printissnsid = $row['pissnsid'];
     if($check_num_rows == 0){
      echo '';
      } else if($check_num_rows == 1){
          echo $get_printissnsid; 
       }
        }
     } else if($pissnsid){
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT printissn, pissnsid FROM jour_entries WHERE  pissnsid='$pissnsid'");
     $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
    $get_printissn = $row['printissn'];

   if($check_num_rows == 0){
    echo '';
   } else if($check_num_rows == 1){
     echo $get_printissn;    
   } 
    }
   } 
   ?>
```

Now everything is working fine, the problem is when a value is entered in the first text box its showing the corresponding match in the second text box. But in case if the value doesn't match with the two fields and user needs to enter manually the data, the problem arises. When there is no match and user enters a value in first textbox, then the second textbox value disappears. How to solve that?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Could you guide me where to use?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the result is valid before putting it in the other input field:

```
function(result) {
    if (result != '') {   
        document.getElementById('pissnsid').value = result;
    }
});
```

You also need to fix your PHP. The `if ($check_num_rows == 0)` check should not be inside the `while` loops, because the loops will never execute when there are no rows. You don't even need a loop at all -- I assume these queries can only return 1 row. So just call `mysql_fetch_array()` -- if it returns the row, you have a match, otherwise there's no match and you should `echo ''`.

Comment: Same output. When attempt to type on the text box, it empties the other text box when there is no match.

Comment: when there is no match it shows nothing, so user tries to type the value manually at that time the value in the other text box  disappears, that is the only problem.

Comment: Then my code should work, since it checks whether the result is empty, and doesn't change the other value.

Comment: No bro it is getting disappear, I checked it, should i use else there, even though its not working. Because of the keyup event. Any if condition need for keyup or what is your suggestion?

Comment: Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: So I will upload in the server?

Comment: Please wait bro im uploading

Comment: You don't have `if (result != '')` in the Javascript.